Dwarf sunflower grows huge
Is it possible for a dwarf sunflower to grow big like the mammoth sunflower? I planted seeds from my dwarf plants the I planted last year and I have one that is growing  like crazy with multiple  heads is this normal?

sunflowers are not efficient at self-pollination and can freely cross-pollinate with other sunflower varieties. It is likely that the seeds you harvested were hybridized seeds from wild or cultivated varieties nearby. A single flower head contains hundreds of ova, which can each be pollinated individually, leading to a non-homogenous collection of hybridized seeds. Cultivation needs to be done in controlled environments to obtain consistent seeds. Information about this can be easily found by searching 'sunflower cross-pollination'

And all story about F1, F2, F3 and more. Also cross-pollination on same variety may give different form (dominant genes).
